# Visual Studio Code: where does MS WScript IntelliSense support come from?

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsh

I've been working on some scripts for Windows using Visual Studio Code and was surprised that when I type WScript on a line the IntelliSense pops up the correct code completion information, even on my Mac.

[image]

I've read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript) on the VSC website and suspect its either coming out of the built-in JavaScript support or Automatic Type Acquisition from some included library but really would like to find out exactly where this is coming from. So far either my Google-Fu is or nobody has written a thing about it because I can't find any information anywhere. Can anyone answer this one?

Comment: Your problem is what I wish. How do I get intellisense for Wscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built into TypeScript. In VSCode, it's actually easy to find the source because you can press F12 on the definition in code, and it will show you the .d.ts:

[image]

Comment: Hi Rob, have a question for you if you don't mind. On top of WSH I have a custom JavaScript interpreter with some global objects like `WScript`. How can I extend VSCode's intellisense? Apparently writing my own TS interfaces like done in here for WScript should work. To do that, should I write a VSCode extension or, or is it something more complicated that requires me to ask this as a separate question?

Comment: You can write a .d.ts file with typings for your interfaces. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript. If you have any other questions you should ask a separate question.